# How to solve issue No directive found with exportAs 'matAutocomplete'?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-cdk

I work on angular 9 I face issue when add angular material auto complete text box

```
  error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'matAutocomplete'.
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [panelWidth]="auto" (optionSelected)='getchangedoption($event.option.value)'>

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [panelWidth]="auto" (optionSelected)='getchangedoption($event.option.value)'>
```

I try to add lines below to app.module to solve issue but
issue still exist

```
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
 imports: [
   FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
```

auto complete component.html

```
<mat-form-field >
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select Item" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemName">
  
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [panelWidth]="auto" (optionSelected)='getchangedoption($event.option.value)'>
    <mat-option (click)="getselected(exp.itemName,i+1,exp.id)" *ngFor="let exp of this.filteredOptions | async;let i = index" [value]="exp.itemName">
      {{exp.itemName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

current Packages Exist on angular project is :

```
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.9.26",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.15",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13"
```

so How to solve this issue please ?

Comment: so are issue related to package or version of angular or what

Comment: can any one help me i can provide data to solve issue really it take two days without solve issue